# Check if the current date string is within or outside the range of two other dates

Tags: cocoa-touch, date, swift, nsdate, date-formatting

I have 2 date pickers. One is for selecting a start date and the other is for selecting an expiry date. When a selection has been made I convert the date to string format and store the results in a two text fields.

This is how I save to the database:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d" // e.g. September 15
let sDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDateField.text) as NSDate! 
let eDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(expiryDateField.text) as NSDate!

activity["startDate"] = sDate
activity["expiryDate"] = eDate

activity.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

What I intend to do is have a table view display 2 sections: one showing activities that are active, and the other showing activities that are expired/not in date range.

I figured I could do this by taking the current date and checking it was within the start date and expiry date range.

My saved date from above is showing up in parse like this:

[image]

The thing is, I don't want to take the year or time into account. The only thing that matters is the month and day. So for example an activity could run once a year between September 15th and December 20th.

I need a way to check that the current date is within those two dates taking the day (e.g. 15th) of the month into account. So today's date is October 19 and an activity would be in range if its start date was September 15 and its expiry date December 20, but would be out of range/operation if the expiry date was October 18 or start date was October 25.

**So to summarise:**

I will be displaying two sections in a table view. One with active activities and another with non-active out of operation activities.

1. How do take my stored start date and expiry date and easily check the current date is within their range?
2. For the occasions when users pick either a start date or expiry date I need to check if the current date is greater/less than the start date (to be able to decide if the activity should show up or not) or if the current date is greater/less than the expiry date (to be able to decide if the activity has passed or not passed its expiry date.

It would be nice if I could roll 1 and 2 into one function and use it in the table view.

Would be interested to learn how the more experienced programmer would achieve this.

Comment: One way would be to use `NSDateComponents`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the date format "MMMM d" (e.g. "September 15"), you can convert the dates
to a string with the date format "MMdd" (e.g. "0915"). Then you can do a simple
string comparison between the current date, the start date and the expiry date.

For example,

```
"0915" < "1019" < "1220"
```

so October 19 is in the range from September 15 to December 20.

Comment: I will give this a try in the table cellForRowAtIndexPath where I have access to the stored date objects and report back.

Comment: This is kind of working for me but I'm having a problem with the dates in the database. For example start date for an activity is store as Oct 21, 2000, 00:00 but when I'm printing it back it's showing up as 1022 instead of 1021. I'm comparing just strings e.g. "1022" etc so this is slightly confusing.

Comment: Maybe I should just store in the database as strings "MMdd" but I wanted to store as a full date to give me more flexibility when working with same date fields elsewhere.

Comment: How do you store the dates in the database? As *strings* or as *dates*?

Comment: As dates. Exactly how it's shown in the image above. I was thinking as storing as "DDmm" strings straight away but won't this limit what I can do with the date afterwards? Storing as date means I can use that date object in a number of different ways or am I wrong?

Comment: @LondonGuy: Storing dates is fine. Note that the conversion from date to string is done according to the local time zone, perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: I think it is the problem because it seems to be working now after a change to the time. What I do for my question 1 is first check a start date and expiry date fields are not nil. Then I check if start date <= current date if it is then I have another if statement inside that checks if current date is <= expiry date and if that is then it means the date is in range. For my question 2 I will check for either start date or expiry date value in database. If there is a start I will check if current date is < start if it is then activity is non activity.

Comment: For when only an expiry date has been chosen. I would check if the current date is > expiry date or the expiry date is < current date if true then it would mean the activity in question has expired. Thanks for the help.